# Alternatives to VBScript for running scheduled tasks

Tags: c#, windows, scripting, console-application

We inherited a bunch of legacy (10+ years old) VBScript files which use to run on a schedule using Windows task manager.

As part of the infrastructure upgrade we are finding out that old 3rd party (Server Objects) components which the scripts reply on no longer work on Win7 / IIS 7.

So as part of this upgrade effort we are considering re-writing these scripts so they don't reply on 3rd party components.

The core of these "scripts" will be a a bunch of HTTP requests running on a scheduled task.

We plan to replace these scripts with C# console programs.  But before doing so would like to check with the community to check if there are any better alternatives?

High level requirement is to run under a schedule task to make a HTTP requests (passing basic windows authentication) and with access to the local file system to write logs etc.

Does Windows Powershell cut it?

Comment: Yes. PowerShell will give you the full flexibility that comes with the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks but when would you lean towards powershell vs C# console program?  Although this may be a another question...

Comment: Use PS when the script may need to change on the fly. Use a console application when the requirements are more nailed down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

[Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadPodcastsWithPowershell.aspx) is an short example from Scott Hanselman blog about downloading all his podcasts with PowerShell script.

Comment: Can PS run directly from Windows Task Manager?  Or do i need to warp this stuff up within a .BAT file?